# How can I split my Perl code across multiple files?

Tags: perl

My scripts are getting too long. How do I split my code (procedural subs) into multiple Perl files and tell the interpreter to make sense of them?

Kind of like:

```
# -> main.pl

#include "foo.pl"
say_hello();
```

and:

```
# -> foo.pl
sub say_hello {print "hello!"}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you want to do is create one or more modules.  Start by looking over [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html), especially the [Perl Modules section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules).

Since you say you're writing procedural code, you'll want to export functions from your modules.  The traditional way to do that is to use [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) (which comes with Perl), although [Sub::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub::Exporter) is a newer CPAN module that allows for some nice things.  (See also its [Sub::Exporter::Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub::Exporter::Tutorial) for an introduction to exporting functions.)

Modules can be placed in any of the directories listed in the `@INC` variable.  Try `perl -V` to get a list.  You can also use [lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib) to add directories at runtime.  One trick is to use the [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) module to find the location of your script, and then add a directory relative to that:

```
use FindBin;                  # Suppose my script is /home/foo/bin/main.pl
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/lib";  # Add /home/foo/bin/lib to search path
```

Your sample code, converted to a module:
In main.pl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Foo;
say_hello();
```

In Foo.pm:

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter 'import';
our $VERSION = '1.00';
our @EXPORT  = qw(say_hello);

sub say_hello {print "hello!"}

1; # A module must end with a true value or "use" will report an error
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for `do`? http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html

Comment: `do` doesn't help with splitting scripts up into multiple files.

Comment: @reinierpost That's what you think - You just haven't achieved Perl nirvana. ;)

Comment: This answer is valid. `do 'xyz.pl'` or `require 'xyz.pl'` can be used to include other scripts (and any subroutines in those scripts can then be called at will) -- very simple. Try it before knocking it!

Comment: @QuasarDonkey `do` can technically be used to that end.  Any answer that suggests doing so, however, is a bad answer.

Comment: @darch I don't see why. For my own personal projects, I've found it very useful for managing large programs.

Answer (score 0):

put it in the same folder as your class and add `use ClassName` to the top of the calling file.

Also check the [Perl OOP](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perloop.htm#Tutorial) tutorial.